# Keep default value as 0.0 for 0 or NULL for numeric column

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, null

I have a numeric column *Number(28,3)* in which I have to insert value as 0.0 ,
whenever I encounter 0 or NULL/blank at the time of data insertion.

I have tried below :

```
NVL(col_name,0.0)
```

but it's just replacing null values with 0

Comment: Say what? Do you want the data to differentiate between `0` and `0.0`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a matter of displaying the data as required:

```
SQL> create table t1(c1 number(28,3));

Table created.

SQL> insert into t1 values(nvl(null, 0.0));

1 row created.

SQL> select * from t1;

        C1
----------
         0

SQL> col c1 format 999990.0
SQL> select * from t1;

       C1
---------
      0.0
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but I wish to insert the data as 0.0 whenever I encounter 0 or null.

Comment: @Balazs Papp But your solution is limited to be formatted only while using sqlplus, any suggestion for sqldeveloper or toad?

Comment: @AnkitTripathi I repeat: this is a matter of displaying data on the **client** side. It's like asking the database to store dates as 'YYYY/MM/DD' or 'MM-DD-YYYY': irrelevant. The database does not use any of the aforementioned formats. Formatting the data is responsibility of the client. If it is unable to do that, data can be formatted with SQL statements as well when selecting, such as `to_char(col_name, '999990.0')`.